# OSX - Compiling training tools for Tesseract 4.0 -Need to reconfigure project, so there are no errors

Tags: macos, homebrew, tesseract

I followed this wiki (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#macos) .
But when run `make training` ,

I get :

`Need to reconfigure project, so there are no errors`

So how should I compile the training tools?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the output of ./configure, it may contain the below text:
You can not build training tools because of missing dependency.
Check configure output for details.

So you need to check the whole output of ./configure to find the missing dependency and install it.

An example of missing dependency prompt:

configure: WARNING: icu 52.1 or higher is required, but was not found.
configure: WARNING: Training tools WILL NOT be built.
configure: WARNING: Try to install libicu-devel package.